# Prime index of subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

In general what is the significance of a subgroup having a prime index? What does it tell us about the group itself? For instance, let H is a subgroup of G and let H be contained in the center of G. Then, if the index of H is prime, show the group G is abelian.

Comment: If a subgroup $H$ of $G$ happens to be normal, and also has a prime index, then the quotient group $G/H$ has prime order, and thus must be cyclic.